# How to install Typesafe Activator for Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, playframework, netbeans-plugins, playframework-2.6, netbeans-8.2

I recently installed a plugin called "playnb" (Version: 1.4.1) for Netbeans Version 8.2. After the installation of said plugin, the options window of Netbeans opened in a Tab called Play Framework. I got following Errormessage in this Tab

> Please, specify the typesafe activator installation directory. It is required.

The Problem with this is, that i can't find out where to get a typesafe activator.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Typesafe Activator is now Open Source and can be Downloaded at [Link for Typesafe Activator Download](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/download).

After downloading it, it is possible to run the .bat file and let the Programm do the rest for you.